# Microsoft Azure Information Protection pops up when access an Office application (Word, Excel, Outlook)

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-account

When launching any Office 2019 desktop application, I started seeing two back-to-back popups that looked something like this:

[image]

When entering my usual personal email address, I received the error message: "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead." If I clicked cancel, the same dialog would appear--I would need to dismiss that too before getting into the Microsoft Office application.

How can I stop these popups from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are for Office 2019 desktop products:

In my case, the answer was in the Add-Ins section of Office. To get there, launch an Office application, such as Excel, go to the File menu, at the bottom left, click Options. Click the Add-ins item on the left navigation bar:

[image]

If you see an entry for Microsoft Azure Information Protection, this is likely the popups' root cause. At the bottom of the window is a Manage option--choose Excel Add-ins, then click Go.

You should see a dialog like this:

[image]

Select then uncheck, click OK, or click the Remove button (if you know that you do not need the Azure Information Protection platform--more on that in the next paragraph). Click OK on the previous dialog, then close and re-launch the Office application. It should no longer present the Azure Information Protection dialog(s).

If you want to uninstall this Azure add-in for all Office applications, you also can do so in one operation by using the Windows Settings -> Apps and Features dialog. Search for Azure and find the applicable Microsoft Azure Information Protection app. Click Uninstall to remove it from the system.

[image]

If you have any other Account log-on issues, you should resolve them by going to the File menu and clicking the Account item. Look for any warnings or issues on the Account screen that's presented. Try signing out, then signing back in, and be sure that Office is activated. A healthy, activated Office product's Account dialog will look something like this:

[image]